# How to create a linspace-vector with a specified spacing

Tags: matlab

I am given a frequency range with

```
min(frequency) = 1.07 e+10
max(frequency) = 1.275 e+10
max(frequency) - min(frequency) = 2.05 e+09
```

I want to create a vector with a spacing of 0.001 e+10 in between the minimum and the maximum frequency:

```
linspace(min(frequency),max(frequency),205)
```

since `2.05 e+09 / 205 = 0.001 e+10` this should work just fine.

The output vector, however, is:

- 1.07 e+10
- 1.071 e+10
- 1.072 e+10 ...
- 1.08 e+10
- 1.0811 e+10
- 1.0821 e+10

any ideas what could have gone wrong? Why is there an extra 0.0001 appearing in the 5th entry?

Comment: Because you have 205 elements, while you want 205 GAPS between the elements. You need to use 206 as the last input for linspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
So the solution is quite simple. You need to add one to the number of values you want to generate. This should give you the correct solution

```
linspace(min(frequency),max(frequency),206)
```

**Explanation**
The extra 0.0001 is there in every value except the first one. It only shows up at the 4th position, because for the previous values it was not shown because of rounding.

Take the following as an example:
You want values between 0 and one with spacing 0.01.
So the way you do it would be the following:

```
max_value - min_value = 1 - 0 = 1
```

Then you would divide 1 by 0.1 and get 10.
So if you call linspace the following way:

```
linspace(0,1,10) =  
0    
0.1111    
0.2222    
0.3333    
0.4444    
0.5556    
0.6667    
0.7778    
0.8889
1.0000
```

But what you instead want to execute is:

```
linspace(0,1,10 + 1)
```

Which results in the values `0, 0.1, 0.2 , ...`

The problem is that MATLAB want to know the number of values it generates and that includes the first **and** last value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you know the *spacing* that you'd like, it's better to simply use the three-input version of `colon` to do this which is of the form: `start : spacing : end`

```
min(frequency) : 0.001e+10 : max(frequency)
```